# Problema al querer usar un valor obtenido desde Firebase en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Lo que ocurre es que el valor lo obtengo sin problemas, pero al querer usarlo fuera del código donde obtengo el valor, este desaparece y no muestra ningún dato...

Este es el código donde recojo el valor "snapshot1" y lo contengo en la variable "pais", pero al querer usar la variable "pais" fuera de ese código, el valor del "snapshot1" desaparece.

```
firebase.database().ref().child("users empresas").child(useruid).child("País").on("value", function(snapshot1) {
      var pais = snapshot1.val();
    //console.log("El país del usuario es " + snapshot1.val());
    });
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo usar ese valor de snaptshot1 en todos lados sin problemas?

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: Es simple: declaras la variable **fuera de la función**: `var pais="";` y luego, dentro sólo le asignas el valor: `firebase.database().ref().child("users empresas").child(useruid).child("País").on("value", function(snapshot1) {
      pais = snapshot1.val();
    //console.log("El país del usuario es " + snapshot1.val());
    });` Fuera de la función podrás entonces hacer: `console.log("El país del usuario es " + pais);`

El problema es que como lo tienes ahora sólo tienes alcance a la variable **dentro** de la función, al declararla dentro con `var`.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, funciona. @A.Cedano

Comment: Me alegro. He escrito una respuesta para dar la pregunta como solucionada. Cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que al declarar la variable `pais` dentro de la función, la misma sólo podrá ser usada en ese ámbito. Si quieres usarla fuera, debes declararla fuera de ella y asignarle el valor dentro.

Por ejemplo:

```
var pais=""; //aquí la variable existe fuera del ámbito de la función
firebase.database().ref().child("users empresas").child(useruid).child("País").on("value", function(snapshot1) {
      pais = snapshot1.val(); //Aquí asignas un valor a la variable
    });

//Aquí puedes usar la variable, y tendrá el valor asignado dentro de la función
console.log("El país del usuario es " + pais);
```